# XSL/XPATH sum of two nodes based on a condition

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0

Here is my sample XML looks like

```
<Header>
<id> 1234 <id>
<type> abcd <type>
<account>
    <code1>a11 </code1>
    <code2>a12 </code2>
    <expense>
        <cost> 10 </cost>
        <description> Travel </description>
    </expense>
        <expense>
        <cost> 30 </cost>
        <description> Travel </description>
    </expense>
    <expense>
        <cost> 20 </cost>
        <description> Hotel </description>
    </expense>
        <expense>
        <cost> 10 </cost>
        <description> Hotel </description>
    </expense>
</account>
</Header>
```

I need to display the result in an XML format as follows

```
<Header>
<id> 1234 <id>
<type> abcd <type>
<code1>a11 </code1>
<code2>a12 </code2>
<description> Travel </description>
<cost> 40 </cost> <!-- sum of cost nodes, if description is Travel -->
<description> Hotel </description>
<cost> 30 </cost> <!-- sum of cost nodes, if description is Hotel -->
</Header>
```

How do I write the sum of costs in XSLT 2.0 based on the condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="Header/account">
 ...
  <cost><xsl:value-of select="sum(expense[contains(description, 'Travel')]/cost)"/></cost>
...
  <cost><xsl:value-of select="sum(expense[contains(description, 'Hotel')]/cost)"/></cost>
</xsl:template>
```

should do, add the other elements where I put the `...`.